# Got Installation Error INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED while installing apk using Android Studio

Tags: android-manifest

I am trying to install Apk generated using Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 my build details are:

```
ext {
    androidCompileSdk = 33
    androidMinSdk = 22
    androidTargetSdk = 33

    fragmentVersion = '1.3.5'
    daggerVersion = '2.35.1'
    okhttp3Version = '4.9.0'
    timberVersion = '4.7.1'
    materialVersion = '1.3.0'
    coreKtxVersion = '1.3.2'
}
```

I have also tryed by adding android:exported="true" but still getting same error.

My AndroidManifest.xml is looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="org.odk.collect.android"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" /> <!-- Dangerous permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> <!-- Normal permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> <!-- Removed in API 23 -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
        android:required="false" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.Collect"
        android:exported="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/notes"
        android:installLocation="auto"
        android:label="@string/collect_app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:testOnly="false"
        tools:replace="android:label">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.helpscreen"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.secondscreen"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.TrainingMainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".activities.FirstLaunchActivity" android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainMenuActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ScannerWithFlashlightActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.FormEntryActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".activities.FormEntryActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:targetActivity=".activities.FormEntryActivity"
            tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.NotificationActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.DrawActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".gdrive.GoogleDriveActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.InstanceChooserList" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".activities.InstanceChooserList"
            android:exported="true"
            android:targetActivity=".activities.InstanceChooserList"
            tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.odk.instance" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.FillBlankFormActivity"
            android:exported = "true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".activities.FormChooserList"
            android:exported="true"
            android:targetActivity=".activities.FillBlankFormActivity"
            tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.odk.form" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity android:name=".activities.FormDownloadListActivity" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".activities.FormDownloadList"
            android:exported="true"
            android:targetActivity=".activities.FormDownloadListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.odk.collect.android.FORM_DOWNLOAD" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.odk.form" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.DeleteSavedFormActivity"
            android:exported = "true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".gdrive.GoogleSheetsUploaderActivity"
            android:exported = "true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.InstanceUploaderListActivity"
            android:exported = "true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".activities.InstanceUploaderList"
            android:exported="true"
            android:targetActivity=".activities.InstanceUploaderListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity android:name=".activities.InstanceUploaderActivity" android:exported = "true"/>

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".activities.InstanceUploaderActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:targetActivity=".activities.InstanceUploaderActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.odk.collect.android.INSTANCE_UPLOAD" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.odk.instance" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity android:name=".activities.AboutActivity" android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name=".configure.qr.QRCodeTabsActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".preferences.screens.ProjectPreferencesActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.FormHierarchyActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ViewOnlyFormHierarchyActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.GeoPointActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.GeoPointMapActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.GeoPolyActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.FormMapActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.BearingActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:targetActivity=".activities.SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity android:name=".activities.CaptureSelfieActivity" android:exported = "true"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.WebViewActivity" android:exported = "true"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.CaptureSelfieVideoActivity" android:exported = "true"/> <!-- Configure this key by setting GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY in collect_app/secrets.properties. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
            tools:replace="android:value" /> <!-- integer/google_play_services_version -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="false" />
        
        <provider
            android:name=".external.FormsProvider"
            android:authorities="org.koboc.collecv.android.provider.odk.forms"
            android:exported="true" />
        <provider
            android:name=".external.InstanceProvider"
            android:authorities="org.koboc.collecv.android.provider.odk.instances"
            android:exported="true" /> <!-- Enable Shortcuts for Command Actions -->
        <activity
            android:name=".external.AndroidShortcutsActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="ODK Form"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".external.FormUriActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:noHistory="true"
            tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.odk.form" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.odk.instance" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My launcher activity is :

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:targetActivity=".activities.SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

When I compiled by setting  androidTargetSdk = 30 it is working seamlessly.

I am getting this error:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

List of apks:
[0] 'D:.......build\outputs\apk\debug\collect-debug-v1.0.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1536468072.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #473): leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakLauncherActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```